# How to Select Site Point then Zoom to Polygons

Tags: leaflet, javascript

The map has a farmLayer of points and a paddockLayer of polygons. (In some countries farmers use the term *field* instead of *paddock*.) When the farm is selected with a double click the farmLayer is removed. How do I display the paddockLayer and zoom to the extent?

(The paddockLayer was setup in an almost identical way to the farmLayer using `forEachFeature` without the numerical extension.)

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/182594/36168 uses `map.fitBounds(event.layer.getBounds());`. I understanding there is a *map* variable scope issue in the function but `map.fitBounds(e.paddockLayer.getBounds());` does not work. (This is my first javascript experience and I'm still confused by how functions work.)

I tried `setView` as a workaround but it removed the paddockLayer from the map and I want to display paddocks for farms in other areas anyway.

```js
function forEachFeature1(feature, layer) {
  layer.on("dblclick", function (e) {
    map.removeLayer(farmLayer);
    // zoom to paddocks **** fix this - See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/182594/36168
    map.fitBounds(paddockLayer.getBounds());
    map.setView(L.LatLng([-37.045, 145.175], 15));
    // bug above disables next line
    paddockLayer.addTo(map);
  });
}

var farmLayer = L.geoJSON(null, {
  onEachFeature: forEachFeature1,

  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
      radius: 6,
    });
  },
});

$.getJSON(farmurl, function (data) {
  farmLayer.addData(data);
  // zoom to farmLayer
  map.fitBounds(farmLayer.getBounds(), { padding: [12, 12] });
  farmLayer.addTo(map);
});
```

**farmLayer**

```js
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 145.08141,-37.029435 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "No":1,
    "Name":"Landfill",
    "Address":"470 Seymour-Tooborac Road Hilldene",
    "Quality":"success"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 145.044388,-37.016336 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "No":2,
    "Name":" Mitchell Fixed Wing Aero Club",
    "Address":" 470 Seymour-Tooborac Road Hilldene",
    "Quality":"doubt"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 145.190301,-37.0683 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "No":3,
    "Name":" Brave Goose Vineyard Seymour",
    "Address":" 8803 Goulburn Valley Hwy Whiteheads Creek VIC 3660",
    "Quality":"success"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 145.168831,-37.048044 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "No":4,
    "Name":" Reserve",
    "Address":" 9088 Goulburn Valley Hwy Seymour VIC 3660",
    "Quality":"success"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 145.14639,-37.026005 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "No":5,
    "Name":" GVR Quarry",
    "Address":" 5 Selectors Rd Seymour VIC 3660",
    "Quality":"doubt"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 145.192433,-37.02886 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "No":6,
    "Name":" Masjid Al-Sahabah",
    "Address":" 22 Dempsey Rd Seymour VIC 3660",
    "Quality":"success"
    }
  }
]
}
```

**PaddockData** stripped from geoJSON file

```js
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "#0000ff",
        "stroke-width": 2,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "fill": "#555555",
        "fill-opacity": 0,
        "Layer": "Paddock",
        "Name": "Motocross Track",
        "fill-opacity": 0,
        "stroke": "#0000ff"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [145.17590001225471,-37.04998716119057],
            [145.18051207065582,-37.05155092516036],
            [145.18172979354858,-37.05046346505919],
            [145.17880082130432,-37.04861817230589],
            [145.17590001225471,-37.04998716119057]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: For starters, your farm data is not valid JSON: the `coordinates` key is repeated. Do you mean to have three different points? A `MultiPoint` geometry? Second thing: what's the relationship between farms and paddocks? Are they spatially related (i.e. one inside the other)? Clicking on a farm zooms to *which* paddock(s)?

Comment: Put in actual farm data. Paddock data is a demonstration polygon. There is a relationship of many paddocks per farm which would be done with a query. I don't think that is the issue, I haven't presented it or even worked out how to do it yet.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong, see https://plnkr.co/edit/j4kbFQJUEsJzXx1A . Maybe you should create a better reproducible example? Do read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your example is very enlightening, testing that code thoroughly. I'm thinking it has something to do with my test environment - Chrome without web security. I'll test your code in my environment and vice versa.

Comment: I have a general point: please name your functions with names that speak for themselves. Your `forEachFeature1` could be named `forEachFarmFeature`, or, to be even less confusing, use the nomenclature of leaflet, where it is `onEachFeature`, so it should probably be `onEachFarmFeature`.

Comment: @yil_b - good point but I'm still testing to see which functions can be used for both farm and property